# Quiz com listagem, adição de pontos e categorização

Tags: javascript

Olá.
Estou precisando criar um Quiz. Este Quiz consiste em 40 perguntas que valem de 1 a 6 pontos. Após votar nas 40 perguntas é listado todas as 40 perguntas e as respectivas pontuações feitas pelo usuário em ordem da maior pontuação para a menor. Logo após isso o usuário seleciona 3 das perguntas com resposta de valor 5 ou 6 que ele mais gostou. Depois disso é adicionado 4 pontos a cada uma destas respostas que ele mais gostou e depois é listado o tal para o usuário. Cada resposta pertence a um grupo(TF, GG, AI, EV) e onde o numero de pontos se encaixar, gera um gráfico com cada um desses grupos.

O mais longe que consegui chegar com a pouquíssima experiência em javascript que tenho esta abaixo. Sei que é difícil, mas se alguém puder me ajudar.

```
(function() {
var perguntasTotal = [{
idPergunta: 1,
pergunta: ") Eu sonho ser tão bom no que faço que serei constantemente                 consultado como um especialista.",
escolhas: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
respostaUser: 0,
pesoPergunta: 'TF'
}, {
idPergunta: 2,
pergunta: ") Sinto-me mais realizado quando sou capaz de integrar e     gerenciar os esforços dos outros.",
escolhas: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
respostaUser: 0,
pesoPergunta: 'GG'
}, {
idPergunta: 3,
pergunta: ") Eu sonho em ter uma carreira que me dê a liberdade para     realizar o trabalho à minha maneira e fazer meus próprios horários.",
escolhas: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
respostaUser: 0,
pesoPergunta: 'AI'
}, {
idPergunta: 4,
pergunta: ") Segurança e estabilidade são mais importantes para mim do que     liberdade e autonomia.",
escolhas: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
respostaUser: 0,
pesoPergunta: 'SE'
}, {
idPergunta: 40,
pergunta: ") Eu sempre procuro oportunidades que minimizem a interferência     na minha vida pessoal e familiar.",
escolhas: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
respostaUser: 0,
pesoPergunta: 'EV'
}];

var contadorPergunta = 0; //Tracks question number
var selecoes = []; //Array containing user choices
var quiz = $('#quiz'); //Quiz div object

// Display initial question
proximaExibicao();

// Click handler for the 'next' button
$('#proxima').on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

// Suspend click listener during fade animation
if(quiz.is(':animated')) {        
return false;
}
escolha();

// If no user selection, progress is stopped
if (isNaN(selecoes[contadorPergunta])) {
alert('Por favor selecione uma resposta!');
} else {
contadorPergunta++;
proximaExibicao();
}
});

// Click handler for the 'prev' button
$('#anterior').on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

if(quiz.is(':animated')) {
return false;
}
escolha();
contadorPergunta--;
proximaExibicao();
});

// Click handler for the 'Start Over' button
$('#inicio').on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

if(quiz.is(':animated')) {
return false;
}
contadorPergunta = 0;
selecoes = [];
proximaExibicao();
$('#inicio').show();
});

// Animates buttons on hover
$('.button').on('mouseenter', function () {
$(this).addClass('active');
});
$('.button').on('mouseleave', function () {
$(this).removeClass('active');
});

// Creates and returns the div that contains the questions and 
// the answer selections
function criaElementoPergunta(index) {
var elementoQ = $('<div>', {
id: 'pergunta'
});

var header = $('<h2>Pergunta ' + (index + 1) + ':</h2>');
elementoQ.append(header);

//var pergunta = $('<p>').append(perguntasTotal[index].pergunta);
var pergunta = $('<p><span id="idPergunta">' +     perguntasTotal[index].idPergunta + '</span>' + perguntasTotal[index].pergunta +     '</p>');
elementoQ.append(pergunta);

var botaoRadio = criaRadio(index);
elementoQ.append(botaoRadio);

return elementoQ;
}

// Creates a list of the answer choices as radio inputs
function criaRadio(index) {
var listaRadio = $('<div class="questoes-3-itens">');
var item;
var input = '';
for (var i = 0; i < perguntasTotal[index].escolhas.length; i++) {

item = $('<li class="metodo-exibicao metodo-exibicao'+     perguntasTotal[index].escolhas[i] +' resposta resposta'+     perguntasTotal[index].escolhas[i] +'">');
input = '<input type="radio" name="resposta" id="resposta' +         perguntasTotal[index].escolhas[i] + '" value=' +     perguntasTotal[index].escolhas[i] + ' /><label for="resposta' +     perguntasTotal[index].escolhas[i] + '"></label>';
input += perguntasTotal[index].escolhas[i];
item.append(input);
listaRadio.append(item);
}
return listaRadio;
}

// Reads the user selection and pushes the value to an array
function escolha() {
selecoes[contadorPergunta] = +$('input[name="resposta"]:checked').val();
}

// Displays next requested element
function proximaExibicao() {
quiz.fadeOut(function() {
$('#pergunta').remove();

if(contadorPergunta < perguntasTotal.length){
var proximaPergunta = criaElementoPergunta(contadorPergunta);
quiz.append(proximaPergunta).fadeIn();
if (!(isNaN(selecoes[contadorPergunta]))) {
$('input[value='+selecoes[contadorPergunta]+']').prop('checked', true);
}

// Controls display of 'prev' button
if(contadorPergunta === 1){
$('#anterior').show();
} else if(contadorPergunta === 0){

$('#anterior').hide();
$('#proxima').show();
}
}else {
var elementoPontuacao = manage(selecoes, perguntasTotal);
quiz.append(elementoPontuacao).fadeIn();
$('#proxima').hide();
$('#anterior').hide();
$('#inicio').show();
}
});
}


function manage(selecoes, perguntasTotal) {
var out = new Array();
var done = false;

for ( i = 0; i < selecoes.length; i++) {
if (selecoes[i] != perguntasTotal[i].respostaCorreta) {
perguntasTotal[i].respostaCorreta = parseInt(selecoes[i]);
out.push(selecoes[i]);
out.push(perguntasTotal[i]);
} else {
done = true;
}
}
if (done == false) {
out.push(perguntasTotal);
}
console.log(out);
return out;
}

var pergunt = [];

$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
var id = jQuery(this).attr('pergunta');
pergunta = manage(pergunta,id);
});
jQuery('.envia').click(function(){
alert(pergunta);
})



})();
```